# Работа с БД Access в Visual Studio 2015. Создание многопользовательской БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio, access

Имею БД Access и прогу на C# работающую с ней. Пока все тестил в монопользовательском режиме. Но сама программа должна выполнять роль клиентского приложения для офиса кадастрового управления, и поэтому имеет место много пользовательское обращение к одной БД. Как избежать проблем с одновременными подключениями нескольких пользователей, обращение к одним данным, ведь явно будет ужасная потеря целостности.

Comment: сервер писать будите? он у вас и будет монопольно работать с базой. для работы с данными лучше использовать транзакции. А вообще нюансов много, почитайте про трехзвенную архитектуру приложений

Comment: _"Как избежать проблем с одновременными подключениями"_ -- вместо Access использовать SQL Server (есть бесплатные версии). пример использования для картографического сервиса - [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/danmark/cases/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Express/Mail.ru/Mail.ru-Microsoft/4000005498)

Comment: Спасибо, гляну. Но все же есть ли варианты на Accsess? Так как уже немалая часть работы проделана( и переделка всей БД довольно сложна и трудоемка(

Answer (score 3):

Потери целостности, по крайней мере на уровне базы, не будет - Аccess это все-таки база данных, и она обеспечивает целостность всех данных, включая внешние ключи. И да, она полноценно поддерживает транзакции. Т.е. при работе из .NET она практически ничем не отличается от SQL Server, кроме строки соединения.

Но вам придется пересмотреть ваш код на предмет предположений, которые могут быть ложными в случае одновременной работы нескольких пользователей - например, если пользователи будут активно удалять данные - то стоит аккуратно обрабатывать случаи открытия их для отображения.

Единственная реальная проблема с Access - это ограничение на 10 одновременных подключений. Что может стать очень серъезной проблемой при найме 11-го сотрудника :)

Comment: 10 подключений это пока вполне нормально) далее все равно буду на SQL Server перепиливать. Просто сроки горят)А вот по поводу ложных предположений честно говоря не совсем понял. Вообще пока первоначальная тревога в том, что боюсь, что может случиться ситуация, когда будет запись двумя пользователями в одну ячейку. Идеально было бы, что бы одновременно работало только одно подключение к БД, а остальные висели в очереди. Я так понимаю это аналог режима serializable в SQL Server. На счет того, что это очень медленно не беспокоюсь, так как объемы как данных так и сотрудников небольшие.

Comment: @AlexeySazonov если два пользователя пишут в одну ячейку - то кто последний записал, тот и прав (совсем одновременной записи и повреждения access не допустит). у моей конторы есть продукт - система для трекинга времени. отлично работает на обычной расшаренной базе access.

Comment: @AlexeySazonov насчет ложных предположений - например, у вас есть заказ и строки в нем. и есть код, который рассчитывает сумму заказа по строкам. так вот к моменту подсчета суммы по строкам она может отличаться от реальной суммы в базе (т.к. кто-то одновременно добавил строку). Т.е. могут быть ошибки в логической целостности, но не в физической. Но они же будут и в SQL Server (если они вообще возможны в вашем конкретном приложении)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я понял. Буду тестить что выйдет у меня)

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не совсем понятно, как вы собираетесь обеспечивать многопользовательский режим -- то ли это трёхзвенное приложение (т.е. есть middle layer в виде application server), то ли просто клиент-сервер. Предполагаю второе.

Но в случае с MS Access тут особая ситуация -- фактически это файл-сервер. Я в своё время учавствовал в создании приложений, которые используют таким образом .mdb базу. База выкладывается на файловую шару, при подключении с клиента указывается путь к файлу на шаре, естественно, у всех участников должны быть права как на шару, так и на файл. Jet-драйвер корректно обрабатывает блокировки при одновременном доступе к таблицам, тут проблем нет. Но из-за того что это файл-сервер, производительность может проседать.

За чем стоит следить:

1. Размер базы. Если я правильно помню, есть верхний предел размера файла -- кажется, 2 ГБ. Соответственно, ничего пожирающего место, такое как документы в виде полей итп хранить в базе не стоит.
2. Старые данные после удаления остаются в файле базы -- видимо, для ускорения операции удаления. Поэтому, время от времени нужно выполнять чистку базы (Compact/Repair). Для этой операции нужен монопольный доступ к файлу базы.

Про не более 10 подключений -- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/154869 -- это только для 1.1, 2.0, 2.5; для Jet 3.0 уже можно больше. Но ещё может быть ограничение на количество подключений к шаре.

Но в любом случае, надо понимать, что файловая БД -- это только для небольших задач и малого числа пользователей.